# Group data on weekly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck with following problem. How can I group following data in the way that it will sum up count on weekly basis.

```
    +---------------------+-----+
    |          data       |count| 
    +---------------------+-----+
    | 2012-08-01 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-02 00:00:00 |  5  | 
    | 2012-08-03 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-04 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-05 00:00:00 |  8  | 
    | 2012-08-06 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-07 00:00:00 |  8  | 
    | 2012-08-08 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-09 00:00:00 |  2  | 
    | 2012-08-10 00:00:00 |  0  | 
    | 2012-08-11 00:00:00 |  5  | 
    | 2012-08-12 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-13 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-14 00:00:00 |  0  |        
    +---------------------+-----+
```

Output  should be following

```
+----------------------+------+
|     data             | count| 
+--------------------- +------+
| 2012-08-06 00:00:00  |  43  | 
| 2012-08-13 00:00:00  |  21  |
+----------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use a function that "rounds" all your dates to the date you want, maybe something like this:

```
select
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,data), 0) as Monday,
    sum([count]) as [count]
from
    yourtable
group by
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,data), 0)
```

Comment: That original SQL groups Sunday - Saturday weeks always to the Monday, but if you want Sunday - Saturday to be placed in the Sunday, then it's DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,data), 0))